# Laravel not load Facade \Auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, namespaces, facade

i changed the directory of my models in App\Models i have changed this file

config.auth

> ```
> 'providers' => [
>     'users' => [
>         'driver' => 'eloquent',
>         'model' => App\Models\User::class,
>     ],
> ```

class User

> namespace App\Models;

my controller AuthController

> use App\Models\User;

But when i call

> if (Auth::attempt($credentials))

or

> if(Auth::check())

it's is false

Where am I wrong?

if I leave User out of the Models directory and replace the namespace and providers then it works

Comment: Assuming that you did everything right, try dump auto load. If error persists, can you share a screenshot of the error.

Comment: I have no errors, simply Auth :: attempt ($ credential) is false don't load the Facade Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

Comment: Did u run composer dump-auto?

Comment: Your title is misleading. If it's returning false, the facade is loading just fine.